# Vim becomes unresponsive when toggling NERDTREE

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm new to Vim and loving it, but I have an annoying problem; whenever I toggle NERDTREE, I get this message:

> Please wait, caching a Large dir...

Vim then becomes unresponsive until I quit it. I don't know what the default directory is, but if it's a large one, can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default directory is your "home" directory. You can open a different directory by typing its name like this:

```
:NERDTree /path/to/directory
```

or the current directory like that:

```
:NERDTree .
```

Make a custom mapping to make the process faster.

That said, my home directory weights 361 Gb for 187 900 elements and the caching takes about 2 seconds. You might have another problem somewhere.